# Create and insert variables into mysql from for loop using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create an array or variables that can be inserted into the sql query instead of do it manually like in my code below.

Is this possible with the simple php, not using PDO, just some kind of trick that will solve this issue.

You can see that I manually inserted 10 columns and 10 values, can I do it shorter?
So, I want to have a variable/array that will consist pt1-pt10 and another that will be consisted of a[1]-a[10].

```
for($j=1;$j<11;$j++) {
    $a[$j] = "";
}

<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'my_db';
$table = 'jos_answers';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("INSERT into ".$table."(id, title, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8, pt9, pt10) VALUES ((select id from jos_content where title='$title'),'$title','$a[1]','$a[2]','$a[3]','$a[4]','$a[5]','$a[6]','$a[7]','$a[8]','$a[9]','$a[10]')");

?>
```

Comment: just a heads up, you probably dont want to use "mysql_query", its deprecated. see here: http://us3.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

```
for($j=1;$j<11;$j++) {
    $a["pt".$j] = $j;
}


"INSERT into ".$table. "(id, title,".implode(",", array_keys(a)).") VALUES ((select id from jos_content where title='$title'),'$title',".implode(",", array_values(a)).")";
```

Comment: @nKn The first part is just setting a key=>value array. The PHP implode function glues the array keys/values with the "glue" you supply, which is "," in this case. It is pretty clear i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO" . $table . "(id, title,";
$value = " VALUES((select id from jos_content where title='$title'),'$title',";
for($x = 1; $x < 11; $x++){
    $insert .= " pt" . $x . ",";
    $value .= " '$a[" . $x . "]'," //this line is iffy....
}
$insert = substr($insert, 0, -1);//to remove last comma
$value = substr($value, 0, -1);//to remove last comma 
$insert .= ")";//final paren
$value .= ")";//final paren
$sql = $insert . $value; //combine parts
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The reason I think that line is iffy is becuase the ' ' surronding the varibles kinda confuses me. Do you want the varibles value to be inserted to the DB? If so I would go with this line instead:

```
$values .= " " . $a[$x] . ",";
```

If you want the ' and the values go with this:

```
$values .= " '" . $a[$x] . "',";
```

Here is a working example of the code edited a bit obviously because it is not in your SQL environment and you did not give us all the variable values: http://viper-7.com/cDAcRl

Good Luck!